# Trying to add filetype to autocmd produces error

Tags: vim

This is what I'm trying to do, toggle a plugin based on file type

```
au FileType lisp,clojure,scheme VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

produces error:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "clojure":                                                                                                                  
E492: Not an editor command: VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle                                                                                                                       
E492: Not an editor command: VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle                                                                                                                       
E492: Not an editor command: VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle                                                                                                                       
E492: Not an editor command: VimEnter * RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

Where is the error here?

Comment: @melpomene i added the error

Comment: Yeah, that command makes no sense. It's `au <event> <pattern> <command>`; what is this code supposed to do, exactly?

Comment: Toggle rainbow parentheses plugin, but only for clojure files

Comment: What's wrong with `au FileType lisp,clojure,scheme RainbowParenthesesToggle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `VimEnter *`.

Each autocmd should have a single event and pattern, but you specified two of each in yours. The FileType event makes sense for this command, so keep that one.

This should work:

```
au FileType lisp,clojure,scheme RainbowParenthesesToggle
```